# Film Sound Design Contracts

Tags: design, film, contracts

I am a theatrical sound designer, and a play that I worked on has recently been filmed and they have approached me with a seperate contract. They want to give me $5000 for full rights. Should I ask for some points on the net profits, so that I don't lose out if it becomes "big"? The sound design was a major part of the play, winning two awards in NYC and one in LA.

Comment: Not sure but congrats on the awards

Answer (score 2):

its unusual to ask for points.  I'd take the money, hope the show does well, and move on to the next gig.

Answer (score 1):

Late to the game ... sorry.

I have never heard of a sound designer getting points ... ever, and I've been doing this for quite a while now.

Answer (score 0):

I agree, asking for points is unusual.  What would be the risks of asking for more money?  If they specifically want your work then it sounds like you're in a good position to bargain.  If they're currently low on funds try working some form of deferred payment clause into the license agreement if sales go above a certain amount. I don't know anything about the theatre world but $5000 for indefinite rights for an entire plays worth of sound seems low.